# Oracle JDBC not giving expected output on Linux

Tags: java, database, linux, oracle, jdbc

Trying to use Oracle DB and Java application in order to use JDBC on Linux platform.

Downloaded **ojdbc6.jar** and **ojdbc6dms.jar**

Installed **SQLDeveloper** on Linux.

Established a connection in SQLDeveloper with name : **Dummy**

```
UserName : abc
Password : abc
DB Name : oracle
DB port : 8181
```

Table Name in DB : **usertable**
Columns in table : **username,contactnumber**

Table contains **3** entries.

The java code snippet is:

```
package com.demo.oracleDB;


import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JC {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

                try {

                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                    System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;

                }

                System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

                Connection connection = null;

                try {

                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:8181:oracle", "abc",
                            "abc");


                    PreparedStatement Pstmt=connection.prepareStatement("select * from abc.usertable");
                    ResultSet rst=null;

                    rst=Pstmt.executeQuery();

                    System.out.println("Before LOOP");

                    System.out.println("Row is  "  +  rst.getRow());
                    System.out.println("Count is   "   +  rst.getFetchSize());

                    while(rst.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Values from DB are " );
                        System.out.println("UserName  "  +  rst.getString("username"));

                        System.out.println("Contact NUmber   "  +  rst.getString("contactnumber"));
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;

                }

                if (connection != null) {
                    System.out.println("You made it.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
                }
            }

        }
```

The output on Linux is

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Before LOOP
Row is  0
Count is   10
```

**No clue why it is not going inside the ResultSet loop** although the count shows 10. **Only 3 entries are present in the table and still the count is showing as 10.**

***Can someone please tell if the query string is correct.***

Can someone please guide me on how to get it working so that it starts printing data from the table on console.

Comment: The fetch size only controls the buffer allocated to transmit data between the server and the client. It has nothing to do with the number of rows returned by your query. Please read the JavaDocs, they do explain that.

Comment: Okk..Can you please tell me why it is not going inside the while loop. There are 3 entries which are present inside this table.

Comment: If it's not entering the loop, I'd assume there *not* 3 rows in the table. Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: what if you do some inserts from jdbc? will they appear in result set?

Comment: It's shouldnt matter if the inserts are done from JDBC or from an SQL client. if you're reading from the correct database & table you will see the values

Comment: Are you sure you had committed the inserts in SQL Developer before running your Java code?

Comment: There's no output after `Count is`? because "You made it." or "Failed to make connection!" should have been printed at least.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes.Absolutely sure.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes..It does print "You made it".

Answer (score 1):

The fetch size is different from the total number of rows returned.

For example, if your query finds 10,000 matches, it won't return all 10,000 rows from the database. This is where fetch size comes in to play. If fetchSize is 10, then it will initially retrieve the first ten rows.

Comment: There are only 3 rows inside the table. How come the output is showing as 10. Morever why it is not going inside the while loop..

Comment: You're displaying the fetch size not the number of rows as explained above. TBH not sure why its not entering the `while` loop. Will post a workaround in just a tick

Comment: The workaround certainly did not help..However I did copy/paste of the same code in another class file and executed it. It ran perfectly. Still could not figure out what was the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

The fetchSize field is only used as a hint for how many records to return at one time, and is used for performance tuning. If the value isn't specified using setFetchSize(), then the return value of getFetchSize() depends on your driver implementation.

[Statement.getFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getFetchSize%28%29)

The Oracle driver implementation probably has a default fetchSize of 10, even if no results are found.

Alternatively, you could call rst.last() and rst.getRow(), which would return the index number of the last row of the ResultSet. Just make sure to call rst.beforeFirst() before you enter your loop.

[ResultSet.getRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29)

As for why your code isn't entering the ResultSet loop, you may need to look at permissions to make sure your database user has access to that table.